# Pass arguments with dot(.) to javascript functions

Tags: c#, javascript, datagridview

I am trying to pass a file name as argument to JS function from a gridview Row (C#) :

```js
onclick='<%# Eval("ImageName", "return loadImage({0})") %>'
```

which gets rendered as:

```js
onclick="return loadImage(Happy.jpg)"
```

and ERROR:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: Happy is not defined
```

When I ***manually*** added single Quotes(' '),It worked properly,Like

```js
onclick="return loadImage('Happy.jpg')"
```

**Now how can I add quotes programatically,OR How can I pass JS parameters with dot(.) ?**

('{0}') did'nt work,Error : "The server tag is not well formed."

===============**SOLUTION**==================

Ok,Solved it like this :

added `onclick="javascript:loadImage(this.src);"`

```js
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/UploadedImages/"+ Eval("ImageName") %>' Height="43px" Width="55px" onclick="javascript:loadImage(this.src);"   CssClass="dlImage" />
```

got full path inside js Function ie

> "http://localhost:52636/ChuttiTime_Alka/UploadedImages/Happy.jpg"

Sliced it to get the file Name

```js
function loadImage(imageName) {
 var bigImage = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FEPropertyImageControl1_propertyBigImage")
 var filename = imageName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
 bigImage.src='../UploadedImages/'+filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,Solved it like this :

added `onclick="javascript:loadImage(this.src);"`

```js
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/UploadedImages/"+ Eval("ImageName") %>' Height="43px" Width="55px" onclick="javascript:loadImage(this.src);"   CssClass="dlImage" />
```

got full path inside js Function ie

> "http://localhost:52636/ChuttiTime_Alka/UploadedImages/Happy.jpg"

Sliced it to get the file Name

```js
function loadImage(imageName) {
 var bigImage = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FEPropertyImageControl1_propertyBigImage")
 var filename = imageName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
 bigImage.src='../UploadedImages/'+filename;
}
```